# Error message with "import-world"

Tags: netlogo

I used "export-world" to export the state of my model. But when I import my world from "import-world", I obtain this error message (I use the time Extension):[image]

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the extension you're using doesn't support `import-world` for the custom data type(s) it defines.

It's something you'd need to take up with the extension's author, or try to hack the extension yourself.

And/or, you could you try to work around it as follows:

- If the extension doesn't provide them, define your own procedures for converting the custom data type to a string and back.
- Before doing `export-world`, convert all of the custom objects to their equivalent strings, replacing them in place.
- After doing `import-world`, reverse the process, converting the strings back to the custom data type.